# Error: Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally. Run `npm install` to download the correct Chromium revision (982053)

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to run puppeteer but I keep getting the error below.

```
C:\Users\Diamo\Documents\Project Laura\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\Launcher.js:105
                throw new Error(missingText);
                      ^

Error: Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally. Run `npm install` to download the correct Chromium revision (982053).
    at ChromeLauncher.launch (C:\Users\Diamo\Documents\Project Laura\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\Launcher.js:105:23)
    at PuppeteerNode.launch (C:\Users\Diamo\Documents\Project Laura\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\Puppeteer.js:125:31)
    at PuppeteerExtra.launch (C:\Users\Diamo\Documents\Project Laura\node_modules\puppeteer-extra\dist\index.cjs.js:129:41)
    at async credittest (C:\Users\Diamo\Documents\Project Laura\laura\credit.js:8:21)
```

Here is my Code, there isn't much here since I'm just trying to figure out if it works.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
  
async function credittest(creditcost) {
    const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
    puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.capitalone.com/');
    page.waitFor(2000)
    await page.click('#ods-input-0')
    await page.keyboard.type('username')
    

    await page.screenshot({ path: './test/example.png' });
    await browser.close();



}

credittest()
```

If anyone is curious on what I'm doing here, I'm trying to automate grabbing balances from my bank account, Capital One *loves* headless browsers and someone told me to use puppeteers stealth plugin. The code ran before, but when I installed the stealth extra is not what I get the error.

Also i did try npm install on puppeteer-core and Puppeteer but nothing came of it.

Comment: You say you ran `npm install` "on puppeteer-core and Puppeteer", but you're using a different package than either of those, `puppeteer-extra`. Did you run `npm i puppeteer-extra`? Can you share your `package.json`? I'm confused: "when I installed the stealth extra is not what I get the error" -- when did you get the error then? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Alright that's a typo on my part, when I installed stealth extra is when I started to get the error, when I installed it I also installed puppeteer core and puppeteer extra, I'll share my package.json when I'm home.